# Do i need bindActionCreators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I was reading this post and I noticed that he is not using the `bindActionCreators` method that comes with `redux`, why is that?

Do I not need it?

here is the post: https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3

Why does it exist if you shouldn't use it? I'm confused.

I've done as he said in the post:

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        fetchQp: (url) => dispatch(qpFetchData(url))
    };
}
```

What's the difference of doing this contra using the `bindActionCreators`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [official documentation](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators) states:

> The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some
>   action creators down to a component that isn't aware of Redux, and you
>   don't want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

What about the post you've mentioned - that guy indeed connects his component to `Redux` - so he is free of using `bindActionCreators` explicitly.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, my question should've been.

"Why and when is bindActionCreators used :)"
But then I don't need it if my whole application is aware of redux?

Comment: @Charlie if you're using `react-redux` - sure. Actually you can read the source files for the `react-redux`'s `mapDispatchToProps.js` which is used in `connect` https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js - they internally use `bindActionCreators`.

Answer (score 4):

These examples are all equivalent:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        fetchQp : (url) => dispatch(qpFetchData(url))
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({fetchQp : qpFetchData}, dispatch);
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchQp : qpFetchData
}

// in all three cases, used as:
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Personally, I recommend using the third form (the "object shorthand").  Just pass an object full of action creators as the second argument to `connect`, and Redux will automatically use `bindActionCreators` internally - there's no good reason to write a separate `mapDispatch` function yourself.